# How do I find out how a particular package got installed?

Tags: debian, package-management

On a particular Debian VM, I want to know how did xterm and x11-utils got installed : were they installed directly (an administrator running `apt-get install xterm` for example) or as a requirement for other packages ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Packages which are installed because they’re dependencies are normally flagged as automatic; you can see that with

```
apt-mark showauto xterm
```

If that outputs `xterm`, the package was installed automatically; otherwise it was installed manually.

You can use `aptitude` to see which dependencies keep a package installed:

```
aptitude why xterm
```

`aptitude why` will also explicitly say if a package was installed manually.